# Example in which $E[E[Y|T,X]] \neq E[Y|T, E[X]]$

Tags: expected-value, causality, dose-response

Context: this question is a follow-up of [this other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/642091/when-does-dose-response-function-estimation-work-better-than-simple-regression/) in which I'm trying to understand why we should use methods for causal inference instead of just training machine learning regressors, especially when dealing with continuous data.

I'm working on a causal dose response estimation problem with a continuous treatment $T$, a confounder $X$ and target $Y$. In such scenario, we are defining $X=\eta_x$, $T=f_t(X,\eta_t)$, and $Y=f_y(T,X,\eta_y)$ where all the $\eta$ terms are independent noise terms and $f$ are generic functions (i.e. they are not necessarily constrained to be linear or to have a specific shape).

Question: I'd like to find an example in which a causal dose response function (DRF) estimated with g-computation is able to correctly retrieve the DRF while a naive method for calculating treatment $T$ influence, that just exploits machine learning to predict $E[Y|T,X=\bar X]$ (where $\bar X$ is the empirical sample mean of $X$) for different levels of $T$, is not.

To me that translates into looking for an example for which
$E_X[E[Y|T,X]] \neq E[Y|T, X=\bar X]$, where the first quantity is the dose response function estimated with g-computation. Is this statistically possible? If so, is there any example?

Some python code or structural equations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure your question has translated into notation well. $E[E[Y|T,X]]$ is, by the law of total expectation, just $E[Y]$. The subscript father down makes it clear you're modeling the marginal association between Y and T. Furthermore, I don't understand how one conditions on a constant, i.e. $E[X]$ in your last expression.

Comment: The notation $E[Y|T, E[X]]$ makes no sense to me.  If interpret it as $E[Y | \sigma(T, E(X))]$, then it is just $E[Y | T]$, which of course doesn't equal to $E[Y]$.

Comment: I think the quantity of interest is actually $E[Y|T, X = \bar{X}]$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I edited the question that hopefully now should be a bit more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, your notation is a bit vague. So I'm going to clarify here exactly how I interpreted things (which I believe is what you meant). You have a model of the form
$$\begin{align*}
Y|T, X &\sim \pi_y(y|t, x) \\
X &\sim \pi_2(x) \\
T &\sim \pi_3(t).
\end{align*}$$
I suppose you could have dependence between $T$ and $X$ without loss of generality, but let's keep it simple.

The first expression you ask about is
$$E_X(E(Y|T=t, X=x))$$
which is equal to $E(Y|T)$ by LoTE. The second expression is
$$E(Y|T=t, X=E(X)).$$
These are not generally the same (as we show by example below) unless the mean of $Y$ is a linear function of $X$ or if $X$ is degenerate.

---

Take a model where the mean of $Y$ is non-linear function of $X$, such as
$$\begin{align*}
Y|T, X &\sim N(T^X, 1) \\
X &\sim N(0, 1)
\end{align*}$$

Now, $$E(Y|T=t, X=E(X)) = t^{E(X)} = t^0 = 1$$

On the other hand,
$$\begin{align*}
E_X(E(Y|T, X)) &= E_X(T^X)
\end{align*}$$
It should be clear that this will not generally be the same as the first case. We can approximate this expectation with Monte Carlo. For example, say that $T=5$ and write

```
set.seed(111)
N <- 1e6
T <- 5
X <- rnorm(N, 0, 1)
Y_given_XT <- rnorm(N, T^X, 1)
mean(Y_given_XT)
```

This returns `3.65124` for me. Note that if you decrease (increase) the variance of $X$, you will get closer to (farther from) the previous answer of $1$.

Comment: Yes, it was exactly what I was asking! Thanks a lot for the reply, and I hope that after having edited my question everything is clear